# If I was a VM how would I treat numbers when executing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, runtime, dynamic-languages, v8

I've been thinking about how to best bridge the gap between CLR world (.NET runtime) and JavaScript and one thing that came to mind was this notion of a type in JavaScript that it is somewhat inferred from the usage while i.e. C# doesn't need to do this.

I'd like to know a little more about the implementation specifics of JavaScript engines specifically regard how your treat a number. The standard outlines a series of operations that are valid in certain contexts and yields certain specific results, strictly speaking, the concept of an integer doesn't exist in JavaScript but there are typical integer arithmetic operations such as bit shift (`>>`) which always operate on a 32-bit signed integer and always yields a 32-bit signed integer.

I guess the hard part is figuring out when a number is an integer and when a number isn't an integer. But how does VMs do this?

```
var x = 1; // is this an integer or a double?
var x = 1.0; // is this an integer or a double?
var x = 2147483648; // is this an integer or a double?
var x = 9007199254740993; // is this an integer, double or runtime error?
```

I'm guessing there's a lot of heuristics that goes into this. I'm specifically looking for some underlying theme that can be sort of used to better reason about these things.

Also from a performance perspective if you realizes that certain numbers are used as integer you can absolutely optimize those situations by sticking to integers. Though, how do you know when to do this?

Any JavaScript VM gurus out there who'd like to take a stab at this? (at this point I'm more interested in the internals of the VM than the actual specifics of the specification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get into the nuts-and-bolts of how JavaScript implementations handle the `Number` type, there's nothing like going to the source. I'd look at:

- [The V8 source code](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source?tm=4) (V8 is Google's JavaScript engine, used in Chrome and NodeJS and some other places. One of the fastest out there.)
- [The SpiderMonkey source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) (SpiderMonkey is Mozilla's engine, used in Firefox)

Comment: Eventually I'd get around to that, I've been poking around the source code of V8 a little bit but I feel a bit like I'm fumbling in the the dark. It's quite a hefty lot of source code.

Comment: Though I have a question for you, what's your take on 64-bit integers in the context of JavaScript?

Comment: @John: Yeah. :-) The good thing is that they tend to mark up the source with the section numbers from the ECMAScript specification, so you can at least find a starting point. But it's dense stuff...

Comment: @John: As far as I'm aware, there are no 64-bit integers in JavaScript at all. All of the JavaScript integer operations are defined as 32-bit operations in the form: Convert `Number` to int32; perform op on int32 value; convert result to `Number`. The only mention of 64-bit integers in the spec is a side-point about implementations being free to use them as a basis for time values if they want. The underlying value of a `Number` is 64-bit, but it's 64 bits of double-precicion floating-point data (IEEE 754).

Comment: Alright, what If I had a 54-bit number like 18014398509481984?

Comment: @John: When you get into the vagaries of what double-precision floating point can represent, you get out of my area of expertise. That particular number seems to be fine: http://jsbin.com/ijahu5 Remember that since these are basically mantissa+exponent, range is a trickier concept than it is for nice, simple integers. More: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Comment: The double can represent any integer up to 53-bits without the loss of precision, that one is 54-bit. I'm surprised it did work though, it could very well be that this particular number is just not subject to rounding errors. I should do a little bit more testing but I do wonder about these things.

Comment: This one will not pass your test, 9007199254740993 and not a single warning is generated by the runtime.

Comment: @John: Well, you wouldn't want an exception thrown by every rounding error, you'd get errors all over the place. :-) I mean, `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`, after all. http://jsbin.com/ilixa6 Most runtimes just define the behaviour of the number types and then happily allow results with out-of-range values to be non-intuitive. For instance, add two positive integers that are both more than half the maximum integer value in Java or C and you'll get a negative result with no errors of any kind. Getting 9007199254740992 instead of 9007199254740993 means your value is precise to 15 digits; not *too* bad...

Comment: It should only be a runtime error when the compiler tries to parse a literal that won't fit into a double without the loss of precision. It would be interesting to know how the runtime reasons behind upgrading numbers like that. e.g. at what point does integer multiplication turn into a double representation (underneath).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - That's quite good, alright. You can represent up to 52-bit integers without the hassle of thinking about overflow and then the double range will take you way beyond that at the loss of precision. The number stuff is all good but how the V8 achieves such an astounding performance is a bit beyond me at the moment. It has to be very perceptive as when to not involve the double representation and stick to integers when possible.

Comment: @John: (The mods are going to come wipe out these comments at some point) Yeah, fair enough on the parsing. On the ints, it's not really all that surprising, given all of the optimizations that V8 does. I mean, if you think about it, you can have your number entity have two states, int and double, and shift between them as necessary. The triggers for when to shift from one to the other are quite clear.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Do I even dare to follow up on this, they should keep their filthy paws out of a perfectly valid discussion.

Comment: @John: StackOverflow isn't a discussion site (and the mod's paws are not filthy). There are specific, intentional, and good reasons why long strands of discussion are chopped. One of the goals of StackOverflow is to avoid the old BB situation where to find the actual *answer* to a question, someone has to trawl through reams and reams of irrelevancy and digression. Early on I should have invited you over to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript but I'm working today...

Comment: Yeah, I've spent enough time to know that, however, at what point do you search the comments for the actual answer? My primary issue is with some moderators that are being somewhat over zealous and destroy something which haven't even had the chance to develop. There really should be a grace period for certain things and sometimes a discussion is merited. This however has now offically gone off-topic.